# Calculate the time for executin instructions with pipeline

Tags: cpu-architecture

Suppose that one instructions requires 10 clock cycles from fetch state to write back state. And we want to calculate the time required to execute 1,000,000 instructions. Each clock cycle takes 2 ns.

(a) Calculate the time required.

The answer says that 1,000,009*2 ns. The last digit 9 is for the number of clock cycles for filling the pipeline. Why is this?? I thought since each instruction fetch is happenin in each clock cycle, it would be 1000000*2 ns.

Comment: What processor architecture are you talking about? I do have an answer but I would like to improve my answer based on the processor you are referring to.

Comment: @Rastikan I guess MIPS.. In my class, we focus on the MIPS. The questions is about MIPS pipeline. thanks!

Comment: The answer is assuming that no pipeline hazards are encountered, so the first instruction completes at the end of cycle 10, the second at the end of cycle 11, and millionth instruction at the end of cycle 1M+9. In a real processor with a 10 stage pipeline, there would be control hazards (e.g., mispredicted branches). Such a "deeply" pipelined processor would almost certainly use caches where misses add delays. If any instruction takes more than one cycle to complete execution, dependencies can introduce stalls. (This also assumes a scalar processor.)

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton So the first 9 clock cycles is for filling the pipeline, 10th clock cycle is when the pipeline is full and the last 9 clock cycles is for emptying the pipeline. And you mean that since we need to caclulate the time to complete 1M instructions, we include the last 9 clock cycles to compute the time. right??

Comment: @eChung00 Yes, the extra 9 cycles are the delay in filling the pipeline. (Technically, the last 9 cycles might not be emptying the pipeline but executing another sequence of instructions.) Yes, the last 9 cycles are part of the execution time (even though they could also be counted as part of the execution time of the next sequence of instructions!).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Alright.. Thank you very much!! now it is clear!

Answer (score 0):

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Let's consider these three instructions.Here you can see for the first instruction it has taken 10 clock cycles and and when coming to next two it will only take 2 more clock cycles, so that for the rest 999 999 instructions it will take more 999 999 clock cycles.Therefore 1 000 000 instructions it will take (10+999 999) 1 000 009 clock cycles.